# Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) in ion-calendar

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4

I am getting this error when running ionic serve.I am using ion2-calender.
The error is shown below

[image]

I used ion-calendar. I referred that from this link..

https://github.com/hsuanxyz/ion2-calendar/tree/91059592243f88318da1afcb2c1ef40356ead2b5

Everything worked fine expect for the back button and some icon.

How to add icons .Where should i make changes.

```
Ionic:

   Ionic CLI                     : 5.4.15 (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ionic)
   Ionic Framework               : @ionic/angular 5.0.0
   @angular-devkit/build-angular : 0.803.25
   @angular-devkit/schematics    : 8.3.25
   @angular/cli                  : 8.3.25
   @ionic/angular-toolkit        : 2.1.2

Utility:

   cordova-res : not installed
   native-run  : not installed

System:

   NodeJS : v10.15.2 (/usr/bin/node)
   npm    : 6.13.6
   OS     : Linux 5.3
```

Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The same error I get for my Ionic icons. What I'm doing is

1. Clearing my browser cache (I'm using Chrome).
2. Ticked disable cache at network tab of dev console at my chrome browser.
3. Restart my browser and application.

and my error is fixed after I'm doing those steps.